# Zabbix-get incomplete string

Tags: linux, bash, centos, zabbix

I have a problem with a receiving data from host to zabbix server. I have the script which make JSON format for zabbix server for discovery rules.

```
#!/bin/bash
TERM=linux

while [ -n "$1" ]
do
case "$1" in​​

.................................................. ...............................

-j) p="$2"
g=$(top -Hbn1 | grep $p | awk '{print $NF}' ORS=',')
IFS=$',' read -r -a customArray <<< $g
echo -e "["
for ((c=0; c<${#customArray[@]}; c++))
do
if ((c==$((${#customArray[@]}-1))));
then
echo -e "{"proc":"${customArray[c]}"}"
else
echo -e "{"proc":"${customArray[c]}"},"
fi
done
echo -e "]"
shift ;;​

.................................................. .................................

esac
shift
done​
```

This script returns the following if execute it from host(agent):

./zabbix_proc.sh -j kworker/85

```
[
{"proc":"kworker/85:0H"},
{"proc":"kworker/85:1H"},
{"proc":"kworker/85:2"},
{"proc":"kworker/85:0"}
]
```

But when I doing the get request from zabbix server with this command:

zabbix_get -s 172.16.164.72 -k di[kworker/85]

I get the output:​

```
[
{"proc":"kworker/85+"},
{"proc":"kworker/85+"},
{"proc":"kworker/85+"},
{"proc":"kworker/85+"}
]
```

Here is incomplete value which ends "+". Everytime I have output limited to 10 symbols with every process which has more than 10 symbols

My config file for zabbix-agent includes the following:

```
UserParameter=di[*],/etc/zabbix/zabbix_proc.sh -j $1
UnsafeUserParameters=1
AllowKey=system.run[*]
```

Help me please to understand it and I will be glad if you have a solution. Thank you :)

**Answer:**

Looks like your top output lines are being truncated when run noninteractively. Try adding -w 200 (or some other value larger than 80 that maybe is the default), like top -Hbn1 -w 200

Also we can use another command:
g=$(ps -e -T | grep $p | awk '{print $NF}' ORS=',')

Comment: have you considered `proc.cpu.util[<name>,<user>,<type>,<cmdline>,<mode>,<zone>]` for the same result?

Comment: yes, but I want monitor by threads and proc.cpu.util doesn't allow it